# Can we put canvas app inside a public site? How this can be achieved?

Tags: force.com-sites, canvas, canvas-app

I am trying to expose canvas app through a public site but I can see that it doesn't work. I can see that there is some request to  /canvas/proxy.jsp which doesn't work inside a public site.

Page Not Found: /canvas/proxy.jsp

Is there a hack or some sophisticated mechanism which would allow to expose a canvas app on public site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like we cannot expose the canvas app via a template-based lightning community.
There is also a salesforce [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E4RpQAK) for the same.